# I'm making a method for product images,price etc and i got this error

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

I'm making a method for product images,price and name.I'm beginner and doin this work my final year project please help me to solve this.

```
 class Singleproduct extends StatelessWidget {
      
      
     
    
      final String? productImage;
      final String? productName;
      final double? productPrice;
      final Function? onTap;
    
      Singleproduct(// this is the error (Use key in widget constructors.)
          {@required this.productImage,
          @required this.productName,
          @required this.productPrice,
          this.onTap});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is shown because of this lint rule:
https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/use_key_in_widget_constructors.html

> DO use key in widget constructors.
>
> It's a good practice to expose the ability to provide a key when
> creating public widgets.
>
> BAD:
>
> class MyPublicWidget extends StatelessWidget { }
>
> GOOD:
>
> class MyPublicWidget extends StatelessWidget {   MyPublicWidget({Key?
> key}) : super(key: key); }

Also check out this video on what keys are:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html